# Permanently register app in Spring Data flow application

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have integrated Spring Data flow and uploaded application jar into the panel. However, whenever I restart the dataflow application I loose the app mapping with JAR. How can I permanently have it in spring-data-flow

I tried various places to register the app permanently but all in vain.

Thanks,
Dhruv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add data source mapping to spring-data-flow application.

By default, it goes for embedded H2 database and hence the deployment gets lost.

Once I added the DB configuration. It was resolved.

Add the following lines in application.properties for mysql

```
server.port=8081
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app_batch
spring.datasource.username=root 
spring.datasource.password= 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Answer (score 0):

SCDF *requires* a persistent RDBMS like MySQL, Oracle and others for production deployments.

The app-registry (i.e., a registry for app coordinates), task/batch execution history, stream/task definitions, audit trails, and other metadata about all of your deployments via SCDF are tracked in the persistent database.

If you don't provide one, by default, SCDF *uses* H2 - an in-memory database. Though it allows you to bootstrap with this database rapidly, it should *not* be used in production deployments. If the server restarts/crashes, the in-memory footprint goes away and a new session is created. That's why persistent storage is a requirement, so it can survive independently even when SCDF restarts.